# progress bar which progresses in function of commands line or copy tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime, jprogressbar

I'm trying to add in my application a progress bar which progresses according to a command line or Java code, my application is a kind of setup or installation Etaps of another program.

all progress bars that I found does not interact with copy task, it means that I do not know when the copy task is finished.

I want my progress bar to progresses in function of these lines command:

```
try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k mkdir \""+dossier+"\\results\" &&"
                    + " mkdir \""+dossier+"\\results\\basededonnees\" &&"
                    + " mkdir \""+dossier+"\\results\\ordonnances\" &&"
                    + " mkdir \""+dossier+"\\results\\piecesjoins\"");

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k mkdir \""+dossier+"\\basededonnees\" &&"
                    + " echo CREATE DATABASE "+nomBase+"; >> \""+dossier+"\\basededonnees\\CreerDB.sql\"");

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k xcopy apps\\lib \""+dossier+"\\lib\" &&"
                    + " set path=%path%;C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.20\\bin &"
                    + " set path=%path%;C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.24\\bin &"
                    + " mysql -u root < \""+dossier+"\\basededonnees\\CreerDB.sql\"");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Une erreur est survenue \n" + ex.getMessage(), "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

dossier = 'C:\Program Files\NameOfMyApps'
nomBase = 'NameOfMyDataBase'

when all the commands and copy tasks are finished I want the bar reach 100%.

thank you in advance, and sorry for the language because I do not metrized a good English

to better explain here is a screenshot:
[enter link description here](http://www.4shared.com/photo/-b2S2bFN/apps.html)

http://www.4shared.com/download/-b2S2bFN/apps.jpg?tsid=20130605-124016-afcd18b4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi see an example below

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Copy {

    private static final String PING_LOCALHOST = "ping localhost";

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.showProgress();
        // first command
        runCommand(progressBar, PING_LOCALHOST, 25);
        runCommand(progressBar, PING_LOCALHOST, 50);
        runCommand(progressBar, PING_LOCALHOST, 75);
        runCommand(progressBar, PING_LOCALHOST, 100);

    }

    private static void runCommand(ProgressBar progressBar, String command, int barValue) throws InterruptedException {
        CopyThread copyThread = new Copy().new CopyThread(command);
        copyThread.start();
        // wait for thread to die
        copyThread.join();
        progressBar.updatePercent(barValue);
    }

    private class CopyThread extends Thread {
        private String cmd;

        public CopyThread(String command) {
            this.cmd = command;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String line;
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

***ProgressBar***

```
package com.test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class ProgressBar {

    private JFrame progressFrame;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ProgressBar() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        progressFrame = new JFrame();
        progressFrame.setTitle("Test progress bar");
        progressFrame.setResizable(false);
        progressFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 640, 79);
        progressFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        progressFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        progressBar.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
        progressBar.setBounds(0, 0, 634, 52);

        progressFrame.getContentPane().add(progressBar);
    }

    public void showProgress() {
        initialize();
        progressFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void closeProgress() {
        progressFrame.dispose();
        progressFrame.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void updatePercent(int value) {
        progressBar.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: everything, every methods are used for already visible JProgressbar must be wrapped in invokeLater

Comment: thank you very much it's work for me! but the progress bar depending on the thread (sleep (2000);) not depending on the command, I don't know if is possible. Obviously this solution work for me just the i had to measure (sleep (time estimate for copying);) thank you again.

Comment: No you shouldn't depend on thread sleep thats only for dummy....If you remote thread sleep then it will depend on the time it takes to copy

Comment: If I remove the thread sleep the progress bar Achieved 100% before the end of copy

Comment: Hi see my updated answer.Its running the ping command wait for the output...there is no three sleep now...it should work with your copy now.